# Understanding interface inside interface(Embedded Interface)

Tags: go, go-interface

I was trying to understand the Interface embedding with the following code.

I have the following:

```
type MyprojectV1alpha1Interface interface {
    RESTClient() rest.Interface
    SamplesGetter
}

// SamplesGetter has a method to return a SampleInterface.
// A group's client should implement this interface.
type SamplesGetter interface {
    Samples(namespace string) SampleInterface
}

// SampleInterface has methods to work with Sample resources.
type SampleInterface interface {
    Create(*v1alpha1.Sample) (*v1alpha1.Sample, error)
    Update(*v1alpha1.Sample) (*v1alpha1.Sample, error)
    Delete(name string, options *v1.DeleteOptions) error
    DeleteCollection(options *v1.DeleteOptions, listOptions v1.ListOptions) error
    Get(name string, options v1.GetOptions) (*v1alpha1.Sample, error)
    List(opts v1.ListOptions) (*v1alpha1.SampleList, error)
    Watch(opts v1.ListOptions) (watch.Interface, error)
    Patch(name string, pt types.PatchType, data []byte, subresources ...string) (result *v1alpha1.Sample, err error)
    SampleExpansion
}
```

Now if I have the follwoing:

```
func returninterface() MyprojectV1alpha1Interface {
//does something and returns me MyprojectV1alpha1Interface
}
temp := returninterface()
```

Now, from the MyprojectV1alpha1Interface if I want to call the

> Create function  of SampleInterface

what I need to do?

Also, please explain me how this interfaces work in Golang.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this definition:

```
type MyprojectV1alpha1Interface interface {
    RESTClient() rest.Interface
    SamplesGetter
}
```

Your `MyprojectV1alpha1Interface` embeds the `SamplesGetter` interface.

Embedding an interface inside another interface means all of the methods of the embedded interface (`SamplesGetter`) can be invoked over the embedding interface (`MyprojectV1alpha1Interface`).

That means you can invoke any of the `SamplesGetter` methods on any object that implements `MyprojectV1alpha1Interface`.

So once you get a `MyprojectV1alpha1Interface` object in your `temp` variable, you can call the `Samples` method (with suitable `namespace`, which I cannot guess from the code you posted):

```
sampleInt := temp.Samples("namespace here")
```

`sampleInt` will then have a `SampleInterface` object, so you can then invoke the `Create` function using your `sampleInt` variable:

```
sample, err := sampleInt.Create(<you should use a *v1alpha1.Sample here>)
```

For more details about how interfaces work, I'd suggest you go to the official specs and examples:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types

https://gobyexample.com/interfaces

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks a lot. I had a understanding of interfaces. But, got confused with interface embedding. But, now its crystal clear. Thanks

Comment: This is very good explanation @eugenioy. But does it mean embedding interfaces into another could pose the risks?

Comment: not sure what you mean by risks @jack_t, embedding is a way to simplify composition in Go