# How to create an interface by combining interfaces from different packages?

Tags: go, interface, rtp, embedding

### Situation

For code base I am using [pion/rtpio](https://github.com/pion/rtpio/tree/f1f9b419644ec92139796aa327d688c74b53bcab/pkg/rtpio) package.

I am trying to extend the interface [`RTPwriter`](https://github.com/pion/rtpio/blob/main/pkg/rtpio/writer.go) by adding a `Close()` function to it. The goal is to make a `NewRTPWritCloser()` function that return a writeCloser with the combined functions.

From the package, I see the author already created the interface `RTPWriteCloser`

```golang
type RTPWriteCloser interface {
    RTPWriter
    io.Closer
}
```

### Attempt

I made this to reuse the function, which is wrong but I didn't know the alternative yet:

```golang
func NewRTPWriteCloser(wc io.WriteCloser) rtpio.RTPWriteCloser {
    writeCloser := rtpio.NewRTPWriter(wc)
    return writeCloser
}
```

and expected that the `wc` have its own `Close()` function ready, so the returned `writeCloser` will satisfy the interface `RTPWriteCloser`. However, I got `(missing method Close)` as an error.

The function `NewRTPWriter()` is like this:

```golang
func NewRTPWriter(w io.Writer) RTPWriter {
    return &RawRTPWriter{
        dst: w,
    }
}
```

### Questions

- How do we create an instance with all desired functions from multiple embedded interfaces at the same time to satisfy the embedding interface ?
- In this example, we want to create `NewRTPWriteCloser` function for `RTPWriteCloser` interface, but we can not create first a writer then add Close function to it ?
- Do I have to create a struct of `RTPWriteCloser` and rewrite all necessary functions that take in that struct ? (seems inefficient)

### Searched

I did my own searching for example: [interfaces inside interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120089/understanding-interface-inside-interfaceembedded-interface) and [combining or extending interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821792/combining-or-extending-interfaces), but they don't get me to the end to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a adapter struct, adding the `io.Closer` semantics to your base type:

```
type WrappingRTPWriteCloser struct {
    w RTPWriter
    c io.Closer
}
```

You should then define the `Close` method to satisfy the interface:

```
func (w *WrappingRTPWriteCloser) Close() error {
    return w.c.Close()
}
```

Then you should create a new reference of your wrapping struct, upon an instance creation:

```
func NewRTPWriteCloser(wc io.WriteCloser) rtpio.RTPWriteCloser {
    writeCloser := WrappingRTPWriteCloser{
            w: rtpio.NewRTPWriter(wc),
            c: wd,
    }
    return writeCloser
}
```

An alternative solution, would be to use the `RTPPipe` function provided out of the box by the package and which returns both an `RTPReadCloser` and a `RTPWriteCloser` instance (piping the `RTPReadCloser` input to the `RTPWriteCloser` output):

```
// RTPPipe creates a new RTPPipe and returns the reader and writer.
func RTPPipe() (RTPReadCloser, RTPWriteCloser) {
    r, w := io.Pipe()
    return &pipeRTPReader{closer: r, rtpReader: NewRTPReader(r, 1500)}, &pipeRTPWriter{closer: w, rtpWriter: NewRTPWriter(w)}
}
```

Comment: quite detail! thank @tmarwen ! The RTPPipe seems like what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will need to create a new struct as you suggest to implement your interface, let's call it `RawRTPWriterCloser` and add the implementation for `Close()`.

You can embed structs in other structs however, so the `Close()` method is the only function you'll need to additionally define:

```
type RawRTPWriterCloser struct {
    rtpio.RawRTPWriter
}

func (rw *RawRTPWriterCloser) Close() error {
    panic("add implementation here")
}
```